# Partial view data not refreshing in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

i have a bootstrap table in asp.net mvc view with a link to open model dialog for selected item id. it calls action method and action methos returns partial view. every thing working on refreshing page but problem is everytime it is showing first time loaded vaues. what i observed in debug is action methos is not calling on every click , it called only for first time. i am not getting where to make change. below is my approach..

Here is HTML

```
<td>
<a href="~/Trainer/DislayTrainerDetails/@item.trainerid" aria-hidden="true" 
 style="cursor:pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-   
 target="#myModalTrainer">More</a>
 </td>
```

popup Model Code :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalTrainer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public ActionResult DislayTrainerDetails(int id)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();

        TrainerService tser = new TrainerService();

        var trainer = tser.GetAllTrainer();

        var c = from i in trainer where i.trainerid == id select i;

        return View("_PartialTrainerDetails", c.FirstOrDefault());
    }
```

please help in this.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you inspect if your link always has the correct id associated with it? `~/controller/action/@item.itemid` may be breaking on your second render.

Comment: it is showing correct item id  when i hover mouse on link.yes  it is showing correct id when hover link, but action is not callingin second render.

Comment: One solution would be to not use a partial view for your modal and simply pass the data in your View Model when the user navigates to that page, populate the modal and render it with the click link.  Is there a reason you are trying to do it this way?  You really should do the majority of your data access before the page is rendered to the user, this way you are not calling out to the DB with every click.

Comment: Try the proposed solution from my last comment and let us know how that goes.

Comment: do u  mean that instead of partial view , use view?

Comment: What I mean is add your modal and link to your main view and just bind the data you want to your View Model.

Comment: tried the solution, i.e. used view insted of partial view for model popup problem still persists.

Comment: If this is the case post your updated code so that we can take a look as to why.